# Stop users from entering only a space and saving (Validation Rule)

Tags: validation

Hello I am looking to continue this conversation on trying to eliminate users from hitting that space bar once or more and then saving a record without adding any letter values.  If I remove the ISBLANK function, it works, but the error fires when I create an opportunity or edit the opportunity and not just when I edit the field.

Can anyone help?

[Santanu helped start the validation in a previous question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/184888/excluding-spacebar-entries-with-letter-validation).

```
LEN(Comment__c)>0 &&
AND($Profile.Name <> "Sales", 
        OR( RecordType.Name = "New", 
    RecordType.Name = "Discounts", 
    RecordType.Name = "Upsell" ), 

        AND( 
        NOT( ISBLANK(Comment__c)), 
        NOT(REGEX(TRIM(Comment__c), "(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).*"))))
```

Comment: I have [moved this discussion to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62531/discussion-on-question-by-awesome-user2-stop-users-from-entering-only-a-space-an).

Answer (score 0):

Use just `ISBLANK(Comment__c)` on the validation rule to check if the field is empty or just whitespace and it will work when editing the record, field and on inserts.

Comment: It cancels out the REGEX function

Comment: What exactly is this regex checking for?

Comment: The regex does not work. It removes leading and trailing white space before checking the regex. Either way SF removed it before the rule is even evaluated anyway

Comment: so I am trying to have at least one letter entered in order to save the values in the text box.  I want the VR to capture that but if I remove the NOT( ISBLANK, the VR fires on creating the record and editing it even though I am not editing that field, so I need to have the NOT(ISBLANK added.  but I can add in spaces and it still saves and it should not....how do I make spaces only show as values?

Comment: You can't do that. As @Eric said: Salesforce will trim the whitespace before all the validation process starts. If you don't want the rule to be fired when you create the record, you should take a look at the `ISNEW()` function.

Comment: that then ignores the REGEX

Comment: But your regex is useless to what you are trying to accomplish. `ISBLANK()` works just fine for what you need to do.